# How to access a superclass instance variable from the subclass?

Tags: javascript, class

everybody!

Suppose that I have this class in JavaScript:

```
function Animal()
{
    this.name = "name";
}

Animal.prototype.someMethod =
    function ()
    {
    }
```

and this subclass:

```
function Cat()
{
    Animal.call(this);
}

Cat.prototype = new Animal();
Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat;

Cat.prototype.someMethod =
    function ()
    {
        // I want to access the superclass "name" instance variable here
    }
```

What's the syntax to access the superclass "name" instance variable from the overriden method in the Cat class?

Thank you.

Marcos

**UPDATED**: Well, if you want to see the real code, here it is. The problem is with the *abc* variable (just a test variable that I was using).

```
var pesquisaAcervo;

$(
    function ()
    {
        carregadoBase();

        if ($("#form\\:tipoPesquisa").val() == "SIMPLES")
        {
            pesquisaAcervo = new PesquisaAcervoSimples();
        }
        else
        {
            pesquisaAcervo = new PesquisaAcervoAvancada();
        }
        pesquisaAcervo.paginaCarregada();
    }
);

// --- PesquisaAcervo ----------------------------------------------------------

function PesquisaAcervo()
{
    $("*:visible[id^='form:materiaisPesquisa']").
        change(this.materialMudado).keyup(this.materialMudado);

    this.abc = 10;
}

PesquisaAcervo.prototype.paginaCarregada =
    function ()
    {
        $("#cabecalhoPesquisa a").click(this.exibirDicasPesquisa);
        $("#cabecalhoPesquisa select").
            change(function () {$("#form").submit();}).
            keyup(function () {$(this).change();});

        $("*:visible[class*='foco']").focus().select();
    };

PesquisaAcervo.prototype.materialMudado =
    function ()
    {
    };

PesquisaAcervo.prototype.exibirDicasPesquisa =  
    function ()
    {
    };

// --- PesquisaAcervoSimples ---------------------------------------------------

function PesquisaAcervoSimples()
{
    PesquisaAcervo.call(this);

    $("#form\\:campos").change(
        function ()
        {
            $("#textoCampo").text($("#form\\:campos :selected").text() + ":");
        }
     ).keyup(function () {$(this).change();}).change();

    $("#pesquisaSimples a").click(
        function ()
        {
            pesquisaAcervo = new PesquisaAcervoAvancada();

            $("#pesquisaSimples").parent().hide();

            $("#pesquisaAvancada").parent().show();

            $("#form\\:tipoPesquisa").val("AVANCADO");
        }
   );
}

PesquisaAcervoSimples.prototype = new PesquisaAcervo();
PesquisaAcervoSimples.prototype.constructor = PesquisaAcervoSimples;

PesquisaAcervoSimples.prototype.materialMudado =
    function ()
    {
        alert(this.abc); // "undefined" here
    };

// --- PesquisaAcervoAvancada --------------------------------------------------

function PesquisaAcervoAvancada()
{
     PesquisaAcervo.call(this);
}

PesquisaAcervoAvancada.prototype = new PesquisaAcervo();
PesquisaAcervoAvancada.prototype.constructor = PesquisaAcervoAvancada;
```

Comment: One note: the line `Animal.call(this);` in your `Cat` constructor doesn't really do anything. This isn't Java; there's nothing analogous to `super`.

Comment: @lwburk - this article tells the contrary: [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

Comment: A real super should work like the magic "this" variable and figure out the who the superclass is by itsef. In Javascript to emulate super functionality you need to "staticaly dispatch" the method from the super class. btw, you should try to get a running example on JSFiddle since you aren't doing anything wrong from what we can see.

Comment: @Marcos - That article's `Person.call(this);` is similarly useless. Try commenting it out and running that code -- you'll get the same results. The prototypes are already established by the time `Person` is first invoked. I guess I can imagine a situation where you'd want the "parent" constructor function to run every time a new `Person` is created, but that's all you'd be doing: calling the function (i.e. there's no linkage happening there). Don't do what that article does. Copying their code without knowing what it does is cargo-cult programming.

Comment: @lwburk. I'm afraid it isn't useless. I commented it out in the subclasses and the code in the _PesquisaAcervo_ class constructor wasn't called.

Comment: @Marcos - Which is exactly what I said. All it does is call the function in the context of the "subclass". The example in the article does *nothing* in that "parent" constructor, which makes it useless. I only want to make it clear that it isn't necessary to achieve inheritance in JS.

Comment: @lwburk - by the way, I placed this code `pesquisaAcervo.materialMudado();` after the line `pesquisaAcervo.paginaCarregada();` and it worked. I'll see if there's some problem with this line: `$("*:visible[id^='form:materiaisPesquisa']").change(this.materialMudado).keyup(this.materialMudado);`

Comment: @Marcos - Yep, that's exactly where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual code reveals the problem. The issue is with how you're calling `materialMudado`. It's being invoked as the callback for an event. The keyword `this` inside the callback will refer to the target of the event (which has no `abc` property), not to the object that the function "belongs" to.

Here's a simple demonstration:

```
function Test() {};

Test.prototype.callback = function() {
    alert(this);
}

var t = new Test();

$(document).click(t.callback);
```

Output (after clicking page):

```
[object HTMLDocument]
```

Compare to this:

```
function Test() {};

Test.prototype.callback = function() {
    alert(this);
}

var t = new Test();

$(document).click(function() {
    t.callback();
});
```

Output:

```
[object Object]
```

In this second example we close over the variable `t`, retaining a reference to it.

Applying this to your example produces something like this:

```
function PesquisaAcervo() {
    var that = this;
    var callback = function() {
        that.materialMudado();
    };
    $("*:visible[id^='form:materiaisPesquisa']").
        change(callback).keyup(callback);

    this.abc = 10;
}
```

Comment: very, very subtle issue. Thank you a lot, lwburk.

Comment: I discovered the _$.proxy()_ utility, that was designed for use cases like this, where the context is lost. Now it can be simplified to this: `$("*:visible[id^='form:materiaisPesquisa']").change($.proxy(this.materialMudado, this)).keyup(function () {$(this).change();});`.

Answer (score 0):

`this.name` should work. I don't see you overriding the name property in your Cat function so you should be able to just do `this.name` and the protopical chain will do the work to find the first instance of this property which should be `Animal.name`.

Comment: If I just use alert(this.name) from the Cat method, it reports me that it is "undefined".

Comment: @Marcos - How are you creating the new `Cat` instance?

Comment: @lwburk - var animal = new Cat();

Comment: @Marcos - Then it should work. I'm guessing there's something you're not telling us. Please edit your question to show *exactly* the code you are running. Don't put in comments saying that "this is where I want it to work"; show us the *exact* code that's failing for you.

Comment: Here is the jsFiddle of your code working as you have described it http://jsfiddle.net/WA7WR/

Comment: @Keith.Abramo - interesting, but in my case my program simply doesn't work.

Comment: @Keith.Abramo - do you have any guess why my code is not working?

Comment: The issue has to do with your instantiation of your subclass is happening before the classes are properly set up. Move the instantiation logic to the bottom of the js here is a jsfiddle to show what I mean http://jsfiddle.net/ga7m3/

Answer (score 0):

Just use the this keyword:

```
function Animal()
{
    this.name = "name";
}

Animal.prototype.someMethod2 =
    function ()
    {
    }


function Cat()
{
    Animal.call(this);
}

Cat.prototype = new Animal();
Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat;

Cat.prototype.someMethod =
    function ()
    {
        alert(this.name);// I want to access the superclass "name" instance variable here
    }
var c = new Cat();
c.someMethod();
```

Add this code to the bottom, I've just added an alert to your `someMethod` method...

In your example, Cat derives everything from Animal, so it has access to the name variable

Comment: Strange as it seems, it doesn't have access to the name variable from the Cat method. As I said, it is "undefined". This is very non-intuitive for me.

Comment: Did you run the code? As I see lwburk already asked you - how are you creating the Cat instance? You sure you use the new keyword?

Comment: @Niloloff - yes, I've been running my code since yesterday, modifying in in various ways without success.

Comment: Strange as it seems, if I may quote you, the code works for me. I just put it all together an ran it. I edited my answer and put the whole code in there.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as an override for an instance variable.  An instance variable is just a property on the `this` object.  You can read it with:

```
var x = this.name;
```

or assign to it with:

```
this.name = "foo";
```

`this.name` will access the name whether you have an instance of an `Animal` object or an instance of a `Cat` object.

If you want to assign to the `name` property in the `Cat` constructor, you can just do so with

```
this.name = "Cat";
```

Once you have a working instance of an object, properties are just properties and there is no distinction for whether a property was created by a superclass or a subclass.  They're just properties of the object at that point and you access all of them the same way with the `this.propertyName` syntax.